# RC circuit with open switch and calculating energy

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, switches, step-response

Yet again a similar task, however this time I'm supposed to find the energy stored in the capacitor.

This is the circuit:

[image]

And the questions are:

[image]

And this is how far I have come in the problem:

[image]

excuse me for all the white markings, but I've written in swedish so whoever is reading won't get confused.

So my confusion is, I've calculated Req, however I'm not certain if it is correct because the switch was initially open? 
And that leads me to my main question: Should Req be the resistor in my last circuit I've drawn? 
(Since the circuit is open then the resistor (R1) and voltage source goes away)

And I know the formula of the energy stored in the capacitor: w(t) = 1/2CV^2(t), so all I need is the voltage across the capacitor.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capdis.html - plug in your numbers and after 10 us you find that Vc = 1.4715 volts

Comment: For 10 us I got 0.026 V, but I considered 0.8 kohm as Req. How do you get it to be 1.4715 V?

Comment: Never mind, I solved it!

Comment: Did you get 1.4715 volts?

Comment: Yes! I did get the same. :)